# htaccess - remove segment of url with redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Need to use .htaccess to redirect all urls that have `blog-entry` in path like this:

```
http://example.com/blog/blog-entry/blog-title
```

to this:

```
http://example.com/blog/blog-title
```

Tried this per another stack answer, but no luck:

```
RewriteRule ^blog-entry/(.*)$ $1 [L,R=301,QSA]
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your rule with this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.*)/blog-entry/(\S*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2 [R=301,NE,L]
```

Since we're using `THE_REQUEST` here, this rule will work from site root or `/blog`/ directory.